# PowerApps LookUp with ComboBox to create DefaultSelectedItems

Tags: combobox, lookup, powerapps

I am still quite new to PowerApps and I have run into a little problem.

I have a field, calibrator, of type person or group that an individual should fill in if they are filling out the form. So, what I did was auto-populate using Office365Users function to display the name of the users.

I then want to use the said field to fill out another field, Title, that should be auto-populated using a LookUp function to see if the calibrator is equal to another field assigned to, of type person or group. The function I used here was
**LookUp(List, 'Assigned To' = DataCardValue.Selected.DisplayName, Title**(of type single line of text)**)**.

The issue I run into is when I auto-populate the Title field through DefaultSelectedItem, the LookUp function produces a **Expected Table Value** error. I am not sure what the reason for the error is, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide a bit more detail. "making a field take in a users display name and associating it to a column within the list " -- It's not clear what that means. Do you want to create a dropdown with a list of people names that already exist in the list column?

Comment: I have just changed it, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using combobox, If you look carefully at the property it's DefaultSelectedItem**s**.

So you need to use Filter instead Lookup hence the error saying Table Value is expected. Try this

```
Filter(List, 'Assigned To' = DataCardValue.Selected.DisplayName)
```

And if you want to display **Title**, you need to change DisplayFields property to

```
["Title"]
```

Comment: So my DIsplayField property was already set to ["Title"]. 

I have also changed my Assigned To to a Text value rather than person or group. And with your Filter I am presented with a circular reference error.

Comment: Circular error mean infinite loop. Does your Combo box control depend on another Combo box control by any chance?

Comment: Yea, that was the idea that I had. I had made the Title combobox auto-populate through lookup or filter through looking at another combobox that is filled with the user of the form. That being the calibrator and using it to find the Title from another field called Assigned To.

Comment: Is the other combobox also using the collection List as its Items? If so, you can just extract the value with OtherCombobox.Selected.'Assigned To'.